# Java JFrame Random Position

Tags: java, swing, jframe

May i know how to generate shapes's position randomly within JFrame and able to align shapes evenly in x-direction (horizontal) within the frame without changing their position in the y-direction (vertical) the picture below?

[image]

Comment: anybody who can help to solve this problem?

Comment: https://scontent-kul1-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xpf1/v/t34.0-12/11909689_920540208019150_975328212_n.jpg?oh=05ac81b9ff66aa0a53cc309f4bd6ab12&oe=55D2CD2A

Comment: 2 questions :
1)i want to generate the shapes 's position randomly within JFrame.         2) align shapes evenly in x-direction (horizontal) within the frame without changing their position in the y-direction (vertical). The picture link is above.

Comment: check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15733835/how-do-you-draw-shapes-on-a-jpanel-which-is-within-another-jpanel .use `paintComponent()` method to draw shapes on jpanel

Comment: First,thank you for your reply. The drawing shapes i figure out how to solve d.Me just dont know how to randomly assign a location within the frame to a newly added shape. I think it related with moveTo(int x , int y) if i not wrong.

Comment: you have to create a Arraylist of shapes and then you can change x,y coordinate when you want to reposition .for instance by changing y of drawrect method  `g.drawRect(x, y, width, height);`  and repainting you can change it's y coordinate only

Comment: can i ask how to drag the exist shape  or shapes simultaneously to new position? For example , you drag desktop file to top where actually its original place is bottom of desktop...

Comment: can clarify more  i didn't get it

Comment: You want to align your desktop folder icon to the position that you want. For example,the folder original position is at left bottom of desktop but now you want to drag the folder icon and align it to top right of desktop. I assume desktop is represent by JFrame, folder icon represent by shape and i want to align the position of shape to new position within JFrame by using mouse drag.